# Searching Between Two Dates With A Specific Format

Tags: sql

So I have a table where the dates are formatted as such: 15-Jan-13

That would obviously be January 15th, 2013.

The problem is, when I try to search a date range between 01/01/2014 and SYSDATE, it errors out.

Does anyone know the proper way in which I would format this based off of how my dates are stored?

FYI my raw data is stored as: 15-JAN-13 02.23.27.000000000 PM -05:00

I'm converting it as
TRUNC(variable_name)

Comment: Can you not store the dates as an actual `DATE` datatype?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And much more importantly: do ***not*** store dates as `varchar`.

Comment: @Siyual

FYI my raw data is stored as: 15-JAN-13 02.23.27.000000000 PM -05:00

I'm converting it as
TRUNC(variable_name)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are asking about "sysdate" then I would assume you are using Oracle.  It would also seem that the the column with the dates are not actual in the date format.  Best option would be to change the column to a date type.  If for some reason that isn't an option, the next best thing to do is to translate the text to a date as part of your query:

```
select *
  from foo
 where to_date(your_column, 'dd-Mon-yy') between to_date('01/01/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
                                             and sysdate
```

Note that to_date is expecting it's second argument to match the structure of the date specified so '01/01/2014' would match the date format 'mm/dd/yyyy' and your_column (value: '15-Jan-13') would match a different format 'dd-Mon-yy'.  Once everything is translated to a date, Oracle can perform appropriate date comparisons.

DISCLAIMER: The translation of your_column to a date using to_date means that if an index is defined on your_column, it won't be used.  If this is a large table you can expect sub-optimal performance.  One additional reason to change the column data type to a date.

Comment: Wait, so I entered:

WHERE to_date(cp.FIRST_PUBLISH_TIME, 'dd-Mon-yy') between to_date('01/01/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
                                             and sysdate

But it's still erroring out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?  You alluded in a comment above that FIRST_PUBLISH_TIME might include more than '15-Jan-13' such as a timestamp?  The format argument (dd-Mon-yy) must represent the text ('15-Jan-13') _exactly_.  See http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php for a full list of potential format letters you can use to match the format of FIRST_PUBLISH_TIME.  Quick example with timestamp included to_date('15-Jan-13 13:10:11',  'dd-Mon-yy hh:mi:ss').